# Record ID of lead is not coming in wired property LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, leads, lwc-wire-adapter

I'm using below code for creating LWC path for lead. In getRecord method I'm trying to fetch the lead record which is just loaded. I'm using below code

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import { getPicklistValues } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import { getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import LEAD_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Lead';
import PICKLIST_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Lead.Status';
import { getRecord, getFieldValue  } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { updateRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';

const FIELDS = [
   'Lead.Id',
   'Lead.Status'
];

export default class CustomPathLwc extends LightningElement {

@track selectedValue;
@api recordId;
@track showSpinner = false;

@wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: LEAD_OBJECT })
objectInfo;

@wire(getPicklistValues, { recordTypeId: '$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId', fieldApiName: PICKLIST_FIELD })
picklistFieldValues;

@wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: FIELDS })
record;


get picklistValues() {
    let itemsList = [];
    console.log('Akshat 1 ---' + JSON.stringify(this.record));
    if (this.record.data) {
        if (!this.selectedValue && this.record.data.fields.Status.value) {
            this.selectedValue = this.record.data.fields.Status.value + '';
        }
        if (this.picklistFieldValues && this.picklistFieldValues.data && this.picklistFieldValues.data.values) {
            console.log('got picklist field data');
            let selectedUpTo = 0;
            for (let item in this.picklistFieldValues.data.values) {

                if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(this.picklistFieldValues.data.values, item)) {
                    let classList;
                    if (this.picklistFieldValues.data.values[item].value === this.selectedValue) {
                        classList = 'slds-path__item slds-is-current slds-is-active';
                        selectedUpTo++;
                    } else {
                        classList = 'slds-path__item slds-is-incomplete';
                    }

                    console.log(classList);

                    itemsList.push({
                        pItem: this.picklistFieldValues.data.values[item],
                        classList: classList
                    })
                }
            }

            if (selectedUpTo > 0) {
                for (let item = 0; item < selectedUpTo; item++) {
                    itemsList[item].classList = 'slds-path__item slds-is-complete';
                }
            }
            console.log('im here = ' + this.selectedValue);
            return itemsList;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

handleSelect(event) {
    console.log('in the function', event.currentTarget.dataset.value);
    this.selectedValue = event.currentTarget.dataset.value;
}

handleMarkAsSelected() {
    this.showSpinner = true;
    const fields = {};
    fields.Id = this.recordId;
    fields.Status = this.selectedValue;

    const recordInput = { fields };

    updateRecord(recordInput)
        .then(() => {
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Success',
                    message: 'Status Updated!',
                    variant: 'success'
                })
            );
            console.log('success!');
        })
        .catch(
            error => {
                this.dispatchEvent(
                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: 'Error updating status!',
                        message: error.body.message,
                        variant: 'error'
                    })
                );
                console.log('failure => ' + error.body.message);
            }
        );
    this.showSpinner = false;
}
```

}

When I'm checking record value in picklistValues method its null
Is there anything I'm not doing correctly

This component loads when the record page opens for leads

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Hello , the getRecord wire adapter works asynchronously, and there might be a delay before the record data is available. So to handle this situation, you can update your code by checking if the record data is available before accessing it.